# Cassandra . SSTableLoader Failed to decode value

Tags: cassandra

Doing bulkloading by generating sSTables and then using sstableloader to load the data.

When querying the data on the loaded table, Primary Key data is failed to be decoded. I am seeing below errors.

Error on select query ( Other than primary key columns are getting rendered correctly):

`Failed to decode value '\xe4\xedQ\x9aX\x8dF\xab\x86\xf1\r\xe4]\xc3\x14C' (for column 'first_name') as text: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
Failed to decode value '$q\x9d\x94P\xb9Ni\x9d);\xd0\x1d33~' (for column 'first_name') as text: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2: invalid start byte`

Code to generate SSTables:

`SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter eventWriter = new SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter(directory, partitioner, keySpace, tableName, UTF8Type.instance,null, 64);
         eventWriter.addColumn(compType.builder().add(ByteBufferUtil.bytes("first_name")).build(), ByteBufferUtil.bytes(entry.firstName), timestamp);
                                      eventWriter.addColumn(compType.builder().add(ByteBufferUtil.bytes("last_name")).build(), ByteBufferUtil.bytes(entry.lastName), timestamp);
                                                                      eventWriter.addColumn(compType.builder().add(ByteBufferUtil.bytes("country")).build(), ByteBufferUtil.bytes(entry.countryText), timestamp);`

Table definition:

`CREATE TABLE test4 (
    first_name varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    country text,
    last_name text, 
    ) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
     caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
    comment='' AND
    dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
    gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
    read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
    replicate_on_write='true' AND
    populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
    compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
    compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};`

What should be done to have PrimaryKey decoded properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved.

There is no need of below statement. That means, primary key column does not need to be added separately.

eventWriter.addColumn(compType.builder().add(ByteBufferUtil.bytes("first_name")).build(), ByteBufferUtil.bytes(entry.firstName), timestamp);

It will get added when new row is created.

eventWriter.newRow(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(entry.firstName));